# Read data from a text file that is present between special characters C++

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream

**I have a text file and its content is :**

```
7936< 679605.35295609 , 3161141.47562524>
7921< 679607.3030399 , 3161130.54258483>
7665< 680213.87647184 , 3160915.99598088>
7656< 680211.19156048 , 3160908.59479456>
## 
7936 7665<648.956>
7921 7656<643.388>
7665 7936<648.956>
7656 7921<643.388>
** 
7089< 682175.42686891 , 3160396.97891098>
7087< 682175.45797565 , 3160389.94086698>
%% 
7089 7665<2062.73>
7665 7089<2062.73>
7087 7656<2065.6>
7656 7087<2065.6>
```

I  want to read data present between special characters '##' and '**' and all the data after '%%'and want to ignore '<' & '>' characters. All the values need to stored as double.

For example in this text file I want to read and store:

7936 7665 648.956

7921 7656 643.388

7665 7936 648.956

7656 7921 643.388

7089 7665 2062.73

7665 7089 2062.73

7087 7656 2065.6

7656 7087 2065.6

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Did you tried [`<regex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Comment: `7936 7665<648.956> -> 7936 7665 648.956` that's not ignoring `<` and `>`; ignoring those chars would result in `7936 7665648.956`

Comment: @fabian number present between < > is a different number

Comment: @Ruks can store it as double. Only thing is calculations need to performed from these numbers so cant store them as string